# $K \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ is compact iff it is closed and bounded

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

I want to prove $\Leftarrow$.

I just need one more step, now. If I find a compact set that contains K, then it will finish the proof. Rudin take a k-cell to do that, but before it he proves that every k-cell is compact, and I think I can take a more simple compact to do this step. I has thinked in the closed ball, but don't know how to prove that it is compact. Can anyone help me to find this set, if it really exists? Thanks.

Comment: Proving that a closed ball is compact directly from the definition isn't going to be any easier than proving that a $k$-cell is compact.

Comment: There is no other set that is more simple to prove that is compact and contains $K$? It looks to be simple, but I can't find :c

Comment: What is not simple about a k-cell?

Comment: I need some theorems before to prove it is compact, and I want to know if I can construct some compact set that contains $K$. If not: that's ok, I just want simplify my proof.

Comment: Isn't this in every real analysis book?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One often needs a starting point, on which we do "laborious" work, and from which facts stem smoothly. The starting point often used for the facts about topology of $\mathbb{R}^n$ is the $k-$cell. There are several reasons for this:

1. **It is simple**.
2. It has a natural "combinatorial" presentation. Look up, for instance, the proof that the $k$-cell is compact and you will see that the way the subdivision works is neat.
3. It "dominates" the topology of $\mathbb{R}^n$, in the sense that a lot of sets can be seen from doing something topologically to the $k$-cell.

etc.

Rudin aggrees with this, and proves that the $k$-cell is compact first. The $k$-cell is not only a nice starting point for compactness, but also for connectedness. From the fact that the $k$-cell is connected we can infer a lot of facts about the topology of $\mathbb{R}^n$ (in fact, about many other things too).

But there is [no free meal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/There_ain%27t_no_such_thing_as_a_free_lunch). We need to do work to arrive at those facts. And we choose to do it for the $k$-cell because, among other reasons, it is simple and useful.

Now, to answer the question directly: The $k$-cell is simple enough.

Comment: It is so sad :/ It's like the only sets that we know that are compact before this theorem are finite sets and k-cells

Comment: We can first  show that $A\times B$ is compact if $A$ and $B$ are compact. Then with induction, for $n\geq 2$: If $A_j$ is compact for $j=1,...,n+1$ and if $\prod_1^n A_j $ is compact then $\prod_1^{n+1}A_j=(\prod_1^nA_j)\times A_{n+1}$ is compact. So  a $k$-cell is compact. This is a convenience of using the $k$-cell.